# How to get all root folders of a S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a AWS S3 bucket with the following top level content:

```
folder_1/
folder_2/
folder_3/
random_file.txt
```

All the folders have lots of files and folders inside them.

How can I write a boto3 script that retrieves only the names of the folders in the top level/root of the bucket?

I've been using the following approach:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
root_folders = []
for key in bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/'):
    root_folders.append(key.key)
```

The result is (of course) just `random_file.txt`

The result Im looking for is:

```
['folder_1', 'folder_2', 'folder_3']
```

Comment: So would you want it to read [folder_1, folder_2, folder_3, random_file.txt] or just [folder_1, folder_2, folder_3] ?

Comment: Just the folders!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`list_objects_v2`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), you can retrieve the folders in the `CommonPrefixes` field like this:

```
>>> s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket', Delimiter='/')
{ ..., 
  u'CommonPrefixes': [
     {u'Prefix': 'folder_1/'}, 
     {u'Prefix': 'folder_2/'}, 
     {u'Prefix': 'folder_3/'}
   ]
 }
```